# Cannot delete file with rm, not even with sudo. also cannot change file ownership

Tags: permissions, rm

I have a list of `.gz` files I want to remove (something must have gone wrong during the transfer and are now corrupted) here's the list:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root        8192 May  3 09:42 .  
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root        8192 May  5 09:41 ..  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10937670989 Oct  6  2020 C7AR31_S3_R1_001.fastq.gz  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11002672431 Apr 26  2019 C7AR31_S3_R2_001.fastq.gz  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root        6148 Apr 10 15:39 .DS_Store  
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root           0 Oct 12  2020 listSRAfiles  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10158755320 Apr 26  2019 MBP15_S7_R1_001.fastq.gz  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10286656454 Apr 26  2019 MBP15_S7_R2_001.fastq.gz  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10008917458 Apr 26  2019 MBP2_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10148315950 Apr 26  2019 MBP2_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10589508845 Apr 26  2019 T51_S8_R1_001.fastq.gz  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10768807303 Apr 26  2019 T51_S8_R2_001.fastq.gz  
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root           0 Apr 27 13:42 Tragelaphini
```

I tried `sudo rm -rf *.gz` but did not work

```
rm: cannot remove ‘C7AR31_S3_R1_001.fastq.gz’: Permission denied  
rm: cannot remove ‘C7AR31_S3_R2_001.fastq.gz’: Permission denied  
rm: cannot remove ‘MBP15_S7_R1_001.fastq.gz’: Permission denied  
rm: cannot remove ‘MBP15_S7_R2_001.fastq.gz’: Permission denied  
rm: cannot remove ‘MBP2_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz’: Permission denied  
rm: cannot remove ‘MBP2_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz’: Permission denied  
rm: cannot remove ‘T51_S8_R1_001.fastq.gz’: Permission denied  
rm: cannot remove ‘T51_S8_R2_001.fastq.gz’: Permission denied
```

I tried to change owner (`chown`) but did not work.

Any ideas? (I am quite new to Linux so forgive me if I am missing something)

Comment: What Unix is this (macOS?)? Are the files on a network share? How did you write the files there (what was the transfer command)?

Comment: Have you tried removing them normally, i.e. `rm *.gz`?

Comment: Have you checked if the file system is mounted "read only"?

Answer (score 0):

i'm on Ubuntu on a virtual machine, the files are on a mounted disk and were trasnfered by someone else so I am not sure what command they used

yes sorry i was locked out of my original account!

Comment: Are you the question owner? Are you not able to use the "Steve" account to update the question?